# Get list of following for instagram with php

Tags: php, curl, instagram-api

I'm having issues getting the list of my instagram follows. Please see my code below. What am i doing wrong?

I keep getting this error: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\art\index.php on line 51

```
function connectToInstagram($url){
$ch = curl_init(); //curl handle

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

}

function printFriends($access_token){
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token='.$access_token; 
$instagramInfo = connectToInstagram($url);
$results = json_decode($instagramInfo, true);

//Parse through the information one by one.
foreach($results['data'] as $items){
    $userImageURL = $items['profile_picture'];
     echo '<img src="'.$userImageURL.'"/><br />';
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you've got ?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\art\index.php on line 51

Comment: have you checked to see if there is anything in `$results['data']` before you attempt to iterate through it?

Comment: it returns an empty array. I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

Your function `connectToInstagram()` doesn't return any data...

You need to `return $result;` before the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I just realized. I added it. and it still doesnt work

Comment: Then `var_dump()` your data at each stage to see where you've got it wrong.